# Interpolation in a loop for Multiple datasets in R

Tags: r, interpolation, missing-data

I possess five datasets; however, for the purpose of this inquiry, I will focus solely on the dataset named "Amman_SPEI." This dataset comprises four features spanning the years 1985 to 2021. Regrettably, the data for the year 1985 contains missing values denoted by `NA`. To address this issue, I have attempted to employ the `na.approx` function to interpolate these missing values. Unfortunately, I have encountered errors and my code is not functioning as intended.

Sample Data:

```
dput(head(Amman_SPEI, 20))
structure(list(year = c(1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 1985, 
1985, 1985, 1985, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 1986, 
1986, 1986), Months = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), `SPEI 3` = c(-0.542816, 1.070035, 0.959166, 
1.226661, 1.199124, -0.126137, -0.564504, -1.263788, 1.079133, 
1.437582, 1.60766, -0.113432, -0.853623, -0.816802, 0.963657, 
1.534409, 2.178637, 2.286769, 1.461083, 0.784813), `SPEI 6` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, 0.588497, 1.353635, 0.363394, 0.057288, -0.405793, 0.864856, 
0.818927, 0.46694, 0.887641, 1.238603, 1.406124, 0.533829, 0.729403, 
1.502142, 2.18118, 1.649733, 1.478472), `SPEI 9` = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, -0.197211, -0.052915, 0.964247, 0.974613, 0.77495, 
0.721047, 0.602724, 0.317706, 1.071423, 1.449141, 1.740943, 1.935113, 
1.506283, 1.30779), `SPEI 12` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, 0.826726, 0.873005, 0.839217, 0.80054, 0.640246, 0.878539, 
0.872817, 0.904578, 1.679994, 1.710497, 1.649498)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Code:

```
datasets <- list(Amman_SPEI)

# Define the features/columns to interpolate
features <- c("SPEI 3", "SPEI 6", "SPEI 9", "SPEI 12")

# Function to interpolate missing values
interpolate_missing <- function(data, feature) {
  data %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    mutate(!!feature := na.approx(!!sym(feature))) %>%
    ungroup()
}

# Iterate over datasets and features
for (i in seq_along(datasets)) {
  for (j in seq_along(features)) {
    datasets[[i]] <- interpolate_missing(datasets[[i]], features[j])
  }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?